# Why can't I paste quotation marks into R (running through terminal)

Tags: r, macos, terminal

I used to be able to type up code in text edit and then copy paste the code into R (running R through terminal on my mac). Now when I do this any quotations marks pasted are not recognised by R and need to be typed in manually. I've tried using word and email to paste from and it still doesn't work. Thoughts? I have a fair amount of quotation marks in my code and it's taking a lot of time to have to retype everything!

Comment: If you're pasting from Word, you may be getting hit with smart quotes. Have you tried saving your document/email as .txt and opening it with a sane editor (ie, one that doesn't mess with dumb quotes)?

Comment: Well I'm almost exclusively working from text edit which is a .txt file so that shouldn't be the problem. However I've not tried saving from word to .txt but I might give that ago (currently running script so will test when it finishes). Ta.

Comment: I HAVE THE ANSWER!! Since my mac update text editor (and other programmes) have taken to doing "smart quotes" - changing straight up and down quotes to curly ones. R only wants the straight ones. Turns out there's a setting in edit-> substitutions -> smart quotes you can just turn off. Long standing problem solved!

Comment: You can answer your own question and even accept it. I expect someone (else) will also find it useful ...