# Problem pasting " " from Word into R-studio

Tags: rstudio, cpu-word

I am writing code into Word for a guide but when pasting code that has parentheses back into R-studio the parentheses are black (e.g. not recognized).

Only when I replace 1 single " in R all  the parentheses in a snippet are updated. Minor issue but very annoying.

Any tips?

I tried using the same R font in Word, but to no avail.

**Edit: FIXED**
It was the pesky smart quotes in word's autocorrect options.

Comment: The quotes from word are likely “smart quotes”. (The ones that curve nicely.)

Comment: Turning of the nice curving smart quotes fixed it. Thank you! I hate those automatic features.

Comment: Also answered here.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20220408/why-cant-i-paste-quotation-marks-into-r-running-through-terminal

Answer (score 0):

Turn off typographic quotes or "smart quotes" in Word if you often have this problem:

1. Word options
2. Proofing
3. Autocorrect options
4. Tab "Autoformat as you type"
5. Uncheck "Straight quotes with smart quotes"

While you're at it, you might want to disable the replacement of `--` by an m-dash as well (at least for C++ and it prevents `i--` from getting messed up).

[image: Screenshot]

I have this problem in Powerpoint more often than Word. The same option exists there.